# Is it possible to remove Core-plot rectangle box?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I am using Core-plot to plot vertical bar chart. In that is it possible to remove its border rectangular border box. I want to have a plain graph. Any suggestion or guidance heartily welcomed.

Thanks in Advance,
Naveen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1.If you want to use themes for CPXYGraph, then just to nil

```
graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
CPTheme *theme = [CPTheme themeNamed:kCPPlainWhiteTheme];
[graph applyTheme:theme];

graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
```

2.More quick and easy solution is:

```
[graph applyTheme:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment beryllium's answer, but I think I should. I browsed 3 pages for similar answers and finally found this one.

None of previous posts mentioned the setting of graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil **AFTER** applyTheme. In my project, I adopted certain sample code which put applyTheme at the very end, and I have no idea that setting the border would be overridden by the theme, and failed again and again.